# Авторизация на сайтах с помощью http и cookies

Tags: http, cookie, веб-сервер, авторизация, браузер

Разбираюсь с темой протокола http и cookies. И мне не очень понятно, что значит http протокол без состояния. Как я поняла, это что информация о запросах не должна нигде храниться, ни на сервере, ни на клиенте согласно протоколу. Но так получается, что все сайты делают так, чтобы человеку не нужно было постоянно вводить логин и пароль при доступе на сайт, где требуется авторизация. В браузер в cookies записывается информация о сайте, что мы уже авторизованы и также какая-то информация записывается на сервер, чтобы проверить эти данные. Разве тогда это уже протокол без состояния?

И ещё мне не понятно, если в cookies записывается информация об авторизации на сайтах. То что мешает любым другим сайтам взять эту информацию и на другом компьютере с этими данными войти от имени пользователя на его сайты.

И ещё, смысл сохранять куки, если можно на сервере просто сохранить айпи адрес клиента, который до этого авторизовался?

Можете, пожалуйста, поподробнее объяснить эту тему с авторизацией?

Comment: Куки работают через заголовки в http-запросах. В самом протоколе состояния нет. Так же можно было бы сделать идентификацию пользователя например основываясь на окончаниях адреса или на передаваемых данных. Но выбрали заголовки.

Comment: Куки в браузере доступны только тому сайту, который их установил. Если сделаете такой браузер, который раскрывает куки всем сайтам, тогда ничего не будет мешать их использовать так. Тут всё основано на неизвестности кук другому сайту. Если они станут известны, то ничто не помешает их использовать.

Comment: IP адрес не идентифицирует клиента. Под одним таким адресом может целый город сидеть, а провайдер внутри решает какому клиенту предназначены данные. Поэтому например всякие блокировки по IP не имеют смысла.

Comment: @Pavel Grishaev Но в учебниках пишут, что проблема с безопасностью в том, что как раз сторонние сайты могут перехватывать запросы к исходному сайту и либо менять куки, либо просто их воровать, чтобы потом использовать. Они же как-то считывают эти куки?

Comment: Обычно такое не происходит, иначе куками бы не пользовались. Возможно в этих учебниках общая информация или имеется в виду какая-то конкретная ситуация при которой это возможно, или если куки неверно настроены.

Comment: @Pavel Grishaev я так понимаю, куки передаются в заголовках как любые другие заголовки в виде текста, почему их может прочитать только тот сайт, который их записал?

Comment: Браузер знает от какого сайта куки и не даёт потом другим сайтам их видеть или читать. То, что они в виде текста передаются, не значит, что JS код может их видеть, или что они будут передаваться в запросах на другой сайт. Http запрос и ответ по структуре простые, но браузер имеет сложное поведение, может скрывать или подменять данные. Http - это просто протокол для передачи данных, то что в нём всё открыто, не значит что использующая его программа тоже будет глупой.

Comment: Посмотрите например вот эту "документацию" - https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie , увидите там много настроек безопасности для кук, например HttpOnly

Comment: @Pavel Grishaev такой момент ещё по написанному Вами. Вы говорите о том, что браузер отправляет куки сайта только тому сайту, который эти куки установил и поэтому только у сайта владельца есть доступ к своим кукам. Но как быть с прокси-серверами? Они же считывают всю информацию в отправленном запросе в том числе и куки?

Comment: Ну так прокси не являются чем-то доверительным, это решение на крайний случай, когда другие нормальные варианты не доступны. Если протокол https, то куки они не смогут читать, потому что зашифрованы, а если http, то что угодно могут делать. И при любом протоколе могут следить, подменять данные и прочее в этом духе.